# How to search for court records regarding medical malpractice for a particular physician?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, medical, malpractice

New York state (US) here. I would like to know what tools/sites/etc. I can use for searching any pertinent court records/documents regarding medical malpractice suits against a particular physician.

Ideally, there would be a legal website I could go to, where I could search for *medical malpractice* as the suit type, and an optional field that might allow me to search by the physician's name.

**Does anything even remotely close to this exist?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Court records are public unless the judge ordered them sealed. For NY, [this](http://www.nycourts.gov/courthelp/GoingToCourt/records.shtml) is how you get them.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question about court records, but I suspect it's what you really want.  New York maintains a site where you can search for information about physicians licensed in New York:

https://www.nydoctorprofile.com/

In addition to information about court actions, it also has a link to the office that disciplines licensed physicians, so you can find out about situations that did not make it to trial.  The profiles also have information about the physician's education and where the physician practices.